# Per-Thread Visibility PHPBB

Tags: php, forum, phpbb

I'm trying to implement a registration system for a board I'm running, and I want a forum where every thread is invisible to everyone but the person who started it and the moderator staff.

I want the staff to be able to post and for the person registering to respond, but I haven't been able to find a per-post visibility solution. Are there any mods that perform this task, or is there a hidden setting in the software somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to achieve it **straight out of the box**.

However, there used to be some modifications that try to address exactly the situation you have:

- [Self Auth MOD](http://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=70&t=1305895)
- [The Wizard's Self Auth Mod](http://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=70&t=553033)
- [Topics Only Visible to OP 0.8.1](http://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?f=70&t=543859)

The problem is **most of them are a bit outdated** (abandoned by the original developer), so you **can't be sure they will work without modifications** in the current version of the forum software. But it's probably easier to fix some small problems that occur on the way, than to write a new modification from scratch.

Comment: That's helpful as a start. I ended up using "Topic Author Reply Only" and modifying it quite a bit - not the most elegant solution but it work.

Comment: @AndreiKrotkov could you post the modified version online and provide a link? It could be helpful to others who have this same problem.

Comment: The base code is found [here](http://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?t=1804575). I had to make modifications in the view board php file to skip over posts where the author was not yourself. Unfortunately I don't have a diff as I just edited the files inline...